# RegEx: Replace all lines ending with specific text

Tags: notepad++, regex

Say I have the following text:

- 1 AM_TESTING
- 2 AM_TEST
- 3 something else
- 4 some text AM_TESTING
- 5 some text AM_TESTING new text

Using Notepad++ (or any other editor with `regex` support), I'd like to replace the entire line if that line ends with "AM_TESTING". If the replacement text is "XXX", the end result should be:

- 1 XXX
- 2 AM_TEST
- 3 something else
- 4 XXX
- 5 some text AM_TESTING new text

Tried `AM_TESTING$` but that just replaces "AM_TESTING" only and not the whole line. Then tried `*AM_TESTING$` but that found no matches.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just add a dot . before the *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Find what: `^(.+)AM_TESTING$`
- Replace with: `$1XXX`
- Search mode: `Regular expression`

Comment: Thanks! My bad, but those numbers are in the margin of Notepad++, and not part of the text itself. So used Find = `^.*AM_TESTING$` and Replace = `XXX` to achieve what I wanted. It was the `^.*` that did the trick, and as @Nifle points out `.*AM_TESTING$` would also work.